# Unable to Returns the vCard representation of the specified CNContacts

Tags: objective-c, ios9, cncontact

Trying to get an NSData object with the vCard representation of the contact By using below interface.

```
+ (NSData *)dataWithContacts:(NSArray *)contacts
                   error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error
```

Got an NSData Object when passed one CNContact to that above interface. Here is the working code

```
CNMutableContact * contact = [CNMutableContact new];
contact.middleName = @"Stalin";
contact.contactType = CNContactTypePerson;
contact.givenName = @"Gates";
contact.familyName = @"GemmyApps";
NSData *bufferedData = [CNContactVCardSerialization dataWithContacts:contact error:nil];
```

Unable to get an NSData Object when passed NSArray of CNContacts to that above interface. Here is the code

```
CNContactStore* contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc]init];
NSArray * keysToFetch =@[CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPostalAddressesKey];
NSMutableArray  *arrFetchedcontact = [contactStore unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:[CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier: @[contactStore.defaultContainerIdentifier][0]] keysToFetch:keysToFetch error:nil];
 NSData *bufferedData = [CNContactVCardSerialization dataWithContacts:arrFetchedcontact error:nil];
```

lldb Message : 
Exception writing contacts to vCard (data): A property was not requested when contact was fetched.

Answer (score 0):

this way you can get data by passing array,

```
CNMutableContact * contact = [CNMutableContact new];
contact.middleName = @"Stalin";
contact.contactType = CNContactTypePerson;
contact.givenName = @"Gates";
contact.familyName = @"GemmyApps";

CNMutableContact *contact2 = [CNMutableContact new];
contact.middleName = @"Stalin1";
contact.contactType = CNContactTypePerson;
contact.givenName = @"Gates1";
contact.familyName = @"GemmyApps1";

NSArray *contactArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:contact,contact2,nil];

NSData *bufferedData = [CNContactVCardSerialization dataWithContacts:contactArr error:nil];



NSLog(@"data length %d",bufferedData.length);
NSLog(@"contact is %@",contact);
```